# call a class member to get default parameters for another member function of same class

Tags: c++, function, arguments, default-arguments

I am trying to achieve to call a class member to get default parameters for another member function of same class. Here is what I am doing:

```
class y {
    virtual vector<int> getLabels();
}

class x: public y {
    virtual vector<int> getLabels();
    listGraph getPlanarGraph(const vector<int> &nodeSe=getLabels());    //want to achieve this. Compiler won't agree 
};
```

If nothing is provided *i.e.* called as `obj.getPlanarGraph()` where `obj` is of corresponding type, then I want to get the list of all set of labels in the `graph`. I know I can write an easy wrapper for this like following(see end) but I am more interested in **why** it is not allowed. For the above declaration compile error is: `cannot call member function ‘virtual std::vector<int> baseGraph::getLabels() const’ without object`.

When I provide `this` argument then error is `‘this’ may not be used in this context`.

```
class x: public y {
    virtual vector<int> getLabels();
    listGraph getPlanarGraph(const vector<int> &nodeSe=this->getLabels());    //error here.
};
```

The workaround I think of is:

```
class x: public y {
    virtual vector<int> getLabels();
    listGraph getPlanarGraph(const vector<int> &nodeSet);    //No. 2
    listGraph getPlanarGraph();    //define the function accordingly and call a 'No. 2' from inside.   
};
```

Comment: This is not possible - your workaround is only option here.

Comment: @IwanAucamp okay. But why is this not possible. What problems can we run into if this kind of setup is allowed

Comment: as per c++03/[class.this]/1; `this` is only defined in non-static member function body - and a member may otherwise not be used without an object - so since there is no way to reference your object in the function declaration there is no real option here (at least - none that I can think of).

Comment: The default argument is evaluated in the context of the caller, not in the context of the function being called. That's why it can't use `this` or member functions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - actually neither of the cases you mentioned is true - the default argument to a member function is evaluated in the scope  of the class decleration as per c++11/[dcl.fct.default]
/5 and c++11/[basic.lookup.unqual]. And `this` is not defined there.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - actually c++11/[dcl.fct.default]/9 would also be worth looking at - this clearly mandates that getLabels does not imply class member access _unless it appears as the id-expression of a class member access expression_

Answer (score 0):

```
listGraph getPlanarGraph(const vector<int> &nodeSe=this->getLabels());
```

... isn't possible because when a method is being called, `this` refers to whichever class instance is calling the method, not to an instance of the class to which the method belongs. `this` only refers to the instance of the class to which the method belongs once the method is being executed.

As to why it isn't possible, the line above is somewhat similar to calling the method like this:

```
x xinstance;
const vector<int> nodeSe labels = this->getLabels();
listGraph lg = xinstance.getPlanarGraph(labels);
```

This code would work, but you can see clearly that `this` refers to the instance of whatever class contains the lines of code above, not to `xinstance`. As @Ivan Aucamp pointed out in the comments, however, when it is expressed in a member function declaration, `this` doesn't refer to anything because it isn't defined at that point.

Comment: Actually in `listGraph getPlanarGraph(const vector<int> &nodeSe=this->getLabels());`, `this` does not refer to anything - as there has no meaning in that context. See c++03/[class.this]/1

Comment: @IwanAucamp: I agree that I didn't make that clear. I'll edit my answer to clarify.